# I have a column with more than 100.000 product names, I want to Identify all the pair of words that repeat them selves through out the column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column full of product names and I want to identify all the pair of words that repeat them selves in the products names, I also want to know how many times.

I managed to do it with one key word, but not with pair of words.

[image]

This is what I did to count the words that repeated them selves throug the Column:

```
Sub FindAndCountWords()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim wordsDict As Object
    
    ' Create a dictionary to store words and their counts
    Set wordsDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' Set the worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Find the last row in column A
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop through each cell in column A from A2 to the last row
    For Each cell In ws.Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
        ' Split the cell's content into an array of words
        Dim wordsArray As Variant
        wordsArray = Split(cell.Value, " ")
        
        ' Loop through each word in the array and update the dictionary
        For Each word In wordsArray
            If wordsDict.Exists(word) Then
                ' Increment the count if the word already exists in the dictionary
                wordsDict(word) = wordsDict(word) + 1
            Else
                ' Add the word to the dictionary with count 1 if it doesn't exist
                wordsDict.Add word, 1
            End If
        Next word
    Next cell
    
    ' Output the unique words and their counts to columns C and D
    ws.Range("C2").Resize(wordsDict.Count, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(wordsDict.Keys)
    ws.Range("D2").Resize(wordsDict.Count, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(wordsDict.Items)
End Sub
```

With that code I got this result:
[image]

Then I tried the following code to get the same result but this time for pair of words that repeated them selves through out the column:

```
Sub FindAndCountWordPairs()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim pairsDict As Object
    
    ' Create a dictionary to store word pairs with their counts
    Set pairsDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' Set the worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Find the last row in column A
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop through each cell in column A from A2 to the last row
    For Each cell In ws.Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
        ' Split the cell's content into an array of words
        Dim wordsArray As Variant
        wordsArray = Split(cell.Value, " ")
        
        ' Identify word pairs and update the pairs dictionary
        For i = 1 To UBound(wordsArray)
            For j = i + 1 To UBound(wordsArray)
                Dim pair As String
                pair = wordsArray(i) & " " & wordsArray(j)
                
                If pairsDict.Exists(pair) Then
                    ' Increment the count if the pair already exists in the dictionary
                    pairsDict(pair) = pairsDict(pair) + 1
                Else
                    ' Add the pair to the dictionary with count 1 if it doesn't exist
                    pairsDict.Add pair, 1
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    Next cell
    
    ' Output the unique word pairs and their counts to columns F and G
    ws.Range("F2").Resize(pairsDict.Count, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(pairsDict.Keys)
    ws.Range("G2").Resize(pairsDict.Count, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(pairsDict.Items)
End Sub
```

But I got this result:
[image]

When what im really expecting is the following:
[image]

¿Can some one help me with the second code?

Comment: From your list of Words, characterize them as to `Color`, `Vehicle Type` and `Brand`. Then look for just one of `Vehicle Type` and one of `Color`

Comment: the words are only examples, it can be any product name not necesarly colors, vehicle types and brands.

Comment: The same principal applies. You need to categorize the words into appropriate groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CountPair()
    Dim oDic1 As Object, oDic2 As Object, oDic3 As Object
    Dim aProd, vProd, aWord, vWord, vKey, arrData
    Dim sKey1 As String, sKey2 As String
    Dim i As Long
    Set oDic1 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set oDic2 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set oDic3 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' Load data
    arrData = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    ' Consolidate by Word
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        aWord = Split(arrData(i, 1))
        For Each vWord In aWord
            If oDic1.exists(vWord) Then
                oDic1(vWord) = oDic1(vWord) & "," & arrData(i, 1)
            Else
                oDic1(vWord) = arrData(i, 1)
            End If
        Next
    Next i
    ' Loop through data in Dic1
    For Each vKey In oDic1.keys
        ' Get product name
        aProd = Split(oDic1(vKey), ",")
        oDic2.RemoveAll
        ' Count by Word
        For Each vProd In aProd
            aWord = Split(vProd)
            For Each vWord In aWord
                If oDic2.exists(vWord) Then
                    oDic2(vWord) = oDic2(vWord) + 1
                Else
                    oDic2(vWord) = 1
                End If
            Next
        Next
        ' Count word pair
        For Each vWord In oDic2.keys
            If vWord <> vKey Then
                sKey1 = vKey & " " & vWord
                sKey2 = vWord & " " & vKey
                If oDic3.exists(sKey1) Then
                    If oDic2(vWord) > oDic3(sKey1) Then oDic3(sKey1) = oDic2(vWord)
                ElseIf oDic3.exists(sKey2) Then
                    If oDic2(vWord) > oDic3(sKey2) Then oDic3(sKey2) = oDic2(vWord)
                Else
                    oDic3(sKey1) = oDic2(vWord)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
    ' Write output to sheet
    Range("F:G").Clear
    Range("F1:G1").Value = Array("Pair", "Times")
    Range("F2").Resize(oDic3.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(oDic3.keys)
    Range("G2").Resize(oDic3.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(oDic3.items)
End Sub
```

[image]

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Dictionary object](https://learn.microsoft.comP/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [Range.Resize property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.comP/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: Im sory, I really did try, you think you can help me countig the 3 words most repeated in product names?

Comment: I would suggest that you create a new post [What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions). OP users will help you out.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the `Dictionary` Object

```
Sub Pairs()

    Dim dict As Object
        Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
            Dim cel As Range
            For Each cel In .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            
                Dim words As Variant
                    words = Split(cel.Value2, " ")
                    Dim iWord As Long
                        For iWord = LBound(words) To UBound(words)
                            Dim jWord As Long
                                For jWord = iWord + 1 To UBound(words)
                                    If words(iWord) < words(jWord) Then
                                        dict(words(iWord) & " " & words(jWord)) = dict(words(iWord) & " " & words(jWord)) + 1
                                    Else
                                        dict(words(jWord) & " " & words(iWord)) = dict(words(jWord) & " " & words(iWord)) + 1
                                    End If
                                Next
                        Next
                    
            Next
            
                With .Range("F2").Resize(dict.Count)
                    .Value = Application.Transpose(dict.Keys)
                    .Offset(, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.Items)
                End With
        End With
        
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, without vba you could do something like:

[image]

To save you typing (unlike the data that I typed for you):
formula in cell C2:

```
UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(" ",1,A2:A8)," ",,1),",")))
```

And formula in cell D2:

```
SUM(IFERROR(IF(FIND(C2,A$2:A$8,1)>0,1,0),0))
```

A good exercise to work out what does what and sort your pairs that you need.

And, based on your comment, the words can be whatever.