# I have a column with keywords and another column with product names, I want to match what product names do to what keywords

Tags: excel, vba

Column A has Product Names.
Column E has Keywords in sets of 1, 2 and 3 words.
Column F has a Catalogue Name.

I want Column B to be filled with the Catalogue Name every time a Product Name Fits a Keyword.

[image]

I have over 100.000 rows, how would you do it to make it fast?
Use of Arrays? Dictionaries?

I tried doing nested cycles, but it is highly inefficient and slow.

What this code does is split the first set of keywords in to separate words.
Example: Red Mitsubishi into:
aWord(0): Red
aWord(1): Mitsubishi

Then it separates the first product name in to separate words.
Example: Red Cool Mitsubishi
pWord(0): Red
pWord(1): Cool
pWord(2): Mitsubishi

Then if each word of the first keyword finds an equal word in the words of the first product, then we found a match.

It will do that with each product name. Once it finished it will pass to the second set of keywords and do the same with each and every product name again, that until its finished with all the keywords.

```
Sub MatchinKeyWords()
    Dim keyWordsArr, productNameArr
    Dim i As Long, x As Long, N As Long
    Dim keyword, productWord
    Dim matchFound As Boolean
    Dim matchedRows() As Boolean

    ' Load arrays from ranges
    productNameArr = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    keyWordsArr = Range("D1").CurrentRegion.Value

    ' Initialize the array to track matched rows
    ReDim matchedRows(LBound(productNameArr, 1) To UBound(productNameArr, 1))
    For i = LBound(matchedRows) To UBound(matchedRows)
        matchedRows(i) = False
    Next i

    ' Iterate over keyWordsArr
    For i = LBound(keyWordsArr, 1) + 1 To UBound(keyWordsArr, 1)
        keyword = Split(keyWordsArr(i, 1))

        ' Check against each productNameArr
        For x = LBound(productNameArr, 1) + 1 To UBound(productNameArr, 1)
            ' Skip if this productNameArr row was already matched
            If matchedRows(x) Then GoTo NextProduct

            productWord = Split(productNameArr(x, 1))
            matchFound = True

            ' Check each keyword
            For N = LBound(keyword) To UBound(keyword)
                If IsError(Application.Match(keyword(N), productWord, 0)) Then
                    matchFound = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next N

            ' If match is found
            If matchFound Then
                productNameArr(x, 2) = keyWordsArr(i, 2) ' Fill in the match info
                matchedRows(x) = True ' Mark this row as matched
            End If

NextProduct:
        Next x
    Next i

    ' Print updated productNameArr to the worksheet
    Range("A1").Resize(UBound(productNameArr, 1), UBound(productNameArr, 2)).Value = productNameArr
End Sub
```

Comment: The code works and you want to know if it can be faster? Since there is not really an issue to resolve, question is too broad and not really appropriate for SO.

Comment: Why would it not be approprate? Im looking for a better practice... I dont see the problem in wanting to learn a better form.

Comment: You're doing a lot of repeated splitting.  You split each product again and again (once per keyword row).  Split everything once, store the resulting words in another column, then use regular Excel formulae to do the trivialised lookups.  *(Prepare the data **once**, process the data **once**.)*

Comment: You are asking for new code to be written. SO is a question and answer forum for specific programming issues. Your code works. There is nothing to debug. Responses are likely to be more in nature of opinion. Maybe Power Query and/or Regular Expressions could handle better/faster.

Comment: Why does `Mitsubishi Red Car` match `Mitsubishi Beautiful Green Car`?

Comment: What if more than one Keyword matches? What should return in the case of "FAST MITSUBISHI"?

Comment: @June7 I didnt explain it but, in the code when a product name already matched, in the next cycle it skips that product:

 Code Line 21: If matchedRows(x) Then GoTo NextProduct

Code Line 31:
            If matchFound Then
                productNameArr(x, 2) = keyWordsArr(i, 2) ' Fill in the match info
                matchedRows(x) = True ' Mark this row as matched
            End If

Comment: So just accept whatever the first match returns for each product (if any) and done?

Comment: So if Fast Ferrari would be "Fast Ferrari Mitsubishi Red Car", then it would be matched with "Mitsubishi Red Car" and not with Fast.

That is the importance of placing the most important keywords on top and the least important keywords on the bottom.

Comment: And should MITSUBISHI GREEN CAR return MITSUBISHI from that example Keyword list? At 100,000 rows, might be time to look at migrating to a database app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- To save time, organize keywords in a Dictionary object.
- *Note:* the keyword table is slightly different from yours.

For example,

The first step is to organize keywords. For any product names that include "CAR", it should only validate with the first two keywords.

`objDic("CAR")` is a nested dictionary object with two items.

- [`key`: MITSUBISHI RED CAR `value`: MITSUBISHI]
- [`key`: HYUNDAI UGLY CAR `value`: HYUNDAI]

| Key Words | Catalogue |
| --- | --- |
| MITSUBISHI RED CAR | MITSUBISHI |
| HYUNDAI UGLY CAR | HYUNDAI |
| FAST | SPEED |

---

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, sKey As String
    Dim arrData, arrKW, vProd, vWord, vKey, aKey
    Dim bMatch As Boolean
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' Load key words into Dict
    arrKW = Range("D1").CurrentRegion
    For i = LBound(arrKW) + 1 To UBound(arrKW)
        sKey = arrKW(i, 1)
        For Each vKey In Split(arrKW(i, 1))
            If objDic.exists(vKey) Then
                objDic(vKey)(sKey) = arrKW(i, 2)
            Else
                Set objDic(vKey) = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
                objDic(vKey)(sKey) = arrKW(i, 2)
            End If
        Next
    Next i
    ' Load product name
    Set rngData = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arrData = rngData.Value
    ' Loop through products
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        sKey = arrData(i, 1)
        ' Check each words in product name
        For Each vProd In Split(arrData(i, 1))
            If objDic.exists(vProd) Then
                ' Matching related key words
                For Each vKey In objDic(vProd).Keys
                    bMatch = True
                    For Each vWord In Split(vKey)
                        If InStr(1, sKey, vWord, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                            bMatch = False
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                    ' Fully matching
                    If bMatch Then
                        arrData(i, 2) = objDic(vProd)(vKey)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
    Next i
    rngData.Value = arrData
End Sub
```

btw, If you apply the same logic as in the previous post to organize keywords with more words as dictionary keys, it can save more time for a large dataset.

[Count 3 most repeated words in product names with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77632862/count-3-most-repeated-words-in-product-names-with-vba)

Answer (score 1):

### Match Multiple Joined Keywords

[image]

```vb
Sub MatchinKeyWords()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    ' Keywords
    
    Dim klData() As Variant, krData() As Variant, kCount As Long, k As Long
    
    With ws.Range("E1").CurrentRegion
        kCount = .Rows.Count - 1
        With .Resize(kCount).Offset(1)
            klData = .Columns(1).Value
            krData = .Columns(2).Value
        End With
    End With
    
    ReDim Preserve klData(1 To kCount, 1 To 2)
    
    For k = 1 To kCount
        klData(k, 1) = Split(klData(k, 1))
        klData(k, 2) = UBound(klData(k, 1), 1) + 1
    Next k
    
    ' Products
    
    Dim prrg As Range, plData() As Variant, prData() As Variant, pCount As Long
    
    With ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        pCount = .Rows.Count - 1
        ReDim prData(1 To pCount, 1 To 1)
        With .Resize(pCount).Offset(1)
            plData = .Columns(1).Value
            Set prrg = .Columns(2)
        End With
    End With
    
    ' Do it!
    
    Dim pArr() As String, p As Long
    
    With Application
        For p = 1 To pCount
            pArr = Split(plData(p, 1))
            For k = 1 To kCount
                If .Count(.Match(klData(k, 1), pArr, 0)) = klData(k, 2) Then
                    prData(p, 1) = krData(k, 1)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next k
        Next p
    End With
    
    prrg.Value = prData
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a 4 line powerquery. Right click refresh output as needed

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
keywords = Table.Buffer(Table1),
z= Table.AddColumn(Source,"Catalogue Output", (x)=>Table.SelectRows(keywords, each List.Count(List.Difference(Text.Split([Key Words]," "),Text.Split(x[Product Name]," "))) =0)[Catalogue]{0})
in z
```

[image]

Bring key word table into powerquery with data ... from table/range .... and file ... close and load ... connection only. Bring input table into powerquery with data ... from table/range .... then go into home ... advanced editor and paste in rows 2-4 from code sample. Keep your existing row 1 and make sure it ends with a comma. If  needed change row 2 to use the name of first query you created if it is not Table1. File close and load back to excel

if you want to allow potential for multiple matches use

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
keywords = Table.Buffer(Table1),
z= Table.AddColumn(Source,"Catalogue Output", (x)=>Text.Combine(Table.SelectRows(keywords, each List.Count(List.Difference(Text.Split([Key Words]," "),Text.Split(x[Product Name]," "))) =0)[Catalogue],"//"))
in z
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below uses early binding, so the highlighted references should be added via *Tools* -> *References*:-
[image: screenshot illustrating references required for early binding]

The code is an adaptation of a procedure I had already written (it prompts the user for all inputs, and performs some validation, rather than using any hard-coded references):

```
Sub usingRecordSet()
    Dim xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60         'structured xml document
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rowNodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList     'reference to collection of xml rows
    Dim Child As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement         'to iterate through all row nodes
    Dim index As Long                          'store current row-node number
    Dim source As Range                        'user-selected column of data to be analysed
    Dim length As Long                         'number of rows in source
    Dim answer As VbMsgBoxResult               'store user response for yes/no prompts
    Dim lookupRng As Range                     'user-selected lookup table
    Dim lastCol As Long                        'to store last column of lookup table
    Dim lookup                                 'to hold content of lookupRng in memory for faster iteration
    Dim i As Long                              'to iterate through all lookup values
    Dim dest As Range                          'user-selected starting point for results
    Dim results                                '2d variant-array to hold results
    Dim xmlString As String                    'to hold xml representation of source range
    Dim replacement As String                  'used to update xmlString
    Dim filterCriteria
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    'Prompt for source data
    On Error Resume Next
    Do
        Set source = Application.InputBox("Select the column of data, including the" & vbCr & _
        "header, to be analysed:", "Select source data", , , , , , 8)
    Loop While (source Is Nothing Or source.Columns.Count > 1)
    On Error GoTo 0
      
    'Check that selected data are not filtered
    If source.Cells.Count <> source.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count Then
        MsgBox "Source data cannot be filtered!", vbCritical, "Inappropriate selection!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'Re-define source to exclude headers
    Set source = source.Offset(1, 0).Resize(source.Rows.Count - 1)
    
    length = source.Rows.Count
    
    'Prompt for  the lookup table
    On Error Resume Next
    Do
        Set lookupRng = Application.InputBox("Select the lookup table, including the headers," & vbCr & _
        "with the lookup values in the first column and" & vbCr & _
        "the category values in the last column", "Select lookup table", , , , , , 8)
    Loop While (lookupRng Is Nothing Or lookup.Columns.Count < 2)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    lastCol = lookupRng.Columns.Count
    
    'Re-define lookup table to exclude headers
    Set lookupRng = lookupRng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(lookupRng.Rows.Count - 1)
    
    'Recordset Filter will fail if any lookup value is null so check for this
    If Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(lookupRng.Columns(1)) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "The lookup column cannot contain any empty cells!", vbExclamation, "Invalid lookup table!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'Check for any blank cells in last column
    If Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(lookupRng.Columns(lastCol)) > 0 Then
        answer = MsgBox("The category column is not fully populated!" & vbCr & _
        "Do you wish to continue?", vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "Incomplete categories!")
        If answer = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    End If
    
    lookup = lookupRng.Value2
        
    'Prompt for where results should be displayed
    On Error Resume Next
    Do
        Set dest = Application.InputBox("Select the first cell, on the same row as the" & vbCr & _
        "first item of data, where the results should be displayed", "Select results location", , , , , , 8)
    Loop While (dest Is Nothing Or dest.Row <> source.Row)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    'In case more than one cell selected
    Set dest = dest.Cells(1)
    
    'check if any populated cells will be overwritten
    If Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(dest.Resize(length, 1)) <> length Then
        answer = MsgBox("The results area selected is not completely empty" & vbCr & _
        "Do you wish to continue ?", vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "Overwrite data?")
        If answer = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    End If
       
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
             
    'Initialise 2d array, of same size as source, to store results
    'each element populated with a space so that unresolved results don't register as 0s
    results = source.Parent.Evaluate("CHOOSE(GESTEP(ROW(1:" & length & "),1),"" "")")
    
    'Create xml string from source data
    xmlString = source.Value(xlRangeValueMSPersistXML)
    'Update header data of xml to add a 2nd column
    replacement = """Col1""/>" & vbCrLf & "    <s:attribute type=""Col2""/>"
    xmlString = Strings.Replace(xmlString, """Col1""/>", replacement, 1, 1)
    'Update header data of xml for data type of the 2nd column
    replacement = "</s:AttributeType>" & vbCrLf & _
                        "   <s:AttributeType name=""Col2"" rs:name=""Field2"">" & vbCrLf & _
                        "    <s:datatype dt:type=""int""/>" & vbCrLf & _
                        "   </s:AttributeType>"
    xmlString = Strings.Replace(xmlString, "</s:AttributeType>", replacement, 1, 1)
    
    'Initialise XMLDoc and make it navigable
    Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    xmlDoc.LoadXML xmlString
    xmlDoc.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:x='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel' xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset' xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'"
     
    'Get all the   <z:row Col1="..."/> elements
    Set rowNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("xml/x:PivotCache/rs:data/z:row")
    index = 1
    For Each Child In rowNodes
        'Update them also to have a 'Col2' attribute
        Child.setAttribute "Col2", index
        index = index + 1
    Next Child
    
    'Initialise RecordSet
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open xmlDoc, , adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, -1

        With rs
            'Iterate through first column of lookup table
            For i = 1 To UBound(lookup, 1)
                filterCriteria = "Field1 LIKE '*" & Strings.Join(Strings.Split(lookup(i, 1)), "*' And Field1 LIKE '*") & "*'"
                .Filter = filterCriteria
                'If there are records for current filter criterion
                If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then
                    'Good practice to ensure cursor at first filtered record
                    .MoveLast
                    .MoveFirst
                    'While there are still records satisfying the current filter
                    While (Not .EOF)
                        'update current row of results with category for current filter
                        If results(.Fields(1).Value, 1) = " " Then results(.Fields(1).Value, 1) = lookup(i, lastCol)
                       .MoveNext
                    Wend
                End If
                .Filter = ""
                Next i
        End With

        dest.Resize(length, 1).Value2 = results
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think can get away from looping structure for some sort of object(s) - range, array, collection, dictionary, recordset are all options. I tested with 2 recordsets and 1 array. Returns the same output shown in posted example.

```
Sub GetCat()
    Const adOpenStatic = 3
    Const adLockOptimistic = 3
    Const adCmdText = &H1
    Dim cn As Object, rsS As Object, rsK As Object
    Dim productWordArr, s As Variant, r As Long
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rsS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set rsK = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    cn.Open "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";HDR=Yes';"
    rsS.Open "SELECT [Product Name], [Catalogue Output] FROM [Sheet1$]", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
    rsK.Open "SELECT [Key Words], [Catalogue] FROM [Sheet1$]", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
    r = 2
    Do While Not rsS.EOF
        Range("B" & r).Clear
        productWordArr = Split(rsS![Product Name], " ")
        For Each s In productWordArr
            rsK.MoveFirst
            rsK.Find "[Key Words] LIKE '*" & s & "*'"
            If Not rsK.EOF Then
                Range("B" & r).Value = rsK!Catalogue
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        r = r + 1
        rsS.MoveNext
    Loop
End Sub
```

I expanded test by adding keyword "Ferrari Black" with catalogue "Ferrari" above "Fast". Still returns Catalogue "Speed" (same happens with original code). If this is a possible undesirable scenario, rules of selection need refinement and code modified. Or maybe a complete rethinking of data structure.

Further expanded test by adding "Mitsubishi" Product Name into rows through 100000. Original code runs for 7 seconds but does not populate these new rows. My code does populate but runs 40 seconds.